# Cannot find bounds of current function: конфликт имён, которого не должно было быть

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

На первой же строке основной подпрограммы, вне зависимости от её содержания, получаю ошибку выполнения:

> Cannot find bounds of current function

При том, что с момента последней успешной компиляции приложения изменял только один из модулей, подключённый к программе, но не задействованный в ней.

Локализовав проблему, выяснил, что ошибку вызывает вот этот код нового модуля:

```
type
  FList = class
    private
      type
        TList = (I,R,S,C,B);
        ElementRecord = record
          case TypeList: TList of //Конфликт в этой строке
            I: (IntField:integer);
            R: (RealField:real);
            S: (StrField:shortstring);
            C: (CharField:char);
            B: (BoolField:boolean);
        end;
        ExtArr = Array of ElementRecord;
      var
        RecList: ExtArr;
    protected
      function GetElement (index:integer):variant;
      procedure SetElement (index:integer; Value:variant);
    public
      property Element[index:integer]: variant read GetElement write SetElement;default;
  end;
```

Конфликтующий с аналогичным кодом старого:

```
type
  FMatrix = class
    private
      type
        TypeList = (I,R,S,C,B); //Конфликт в этой строке
        MatrixCellRecord = record
          case TypeMatrix: TypeList of
            I: (IntField:integer);
            R: (RealField:real);
            S: (StrField:shortstring);
            C: (CharField:char);
            B: (BoolField:boolean);
        end;
        MRow = Array of MatrixCellRecord;
        Matrix = Array of MRow;
      var
        MRead: Matrix;
        DCell: MatrixCellRecord;
        //...
    protected
      //...
      function GetCell(n,m: integer):variant;
      procedure SetCell(n,m: integer; Value: variant);
    public
      //...
      property Cell[n,m: integer]: variant read GetCell write SetCell;default;
  end;
```

Достаточно поменять название поля записи в новом модуле так:

```
case ATypeList: TList of
```

**Или** название типа в старом модуле так

```
ATypeList = (I,R,S,C,B);
MatrixCellRecord = record
  case TypeMatrix: ATypeList of
```

И всё начинает работать.

Однако, как вообще возможен подобный конфликт имён, если запись с типом объявлены в блоках `private` двух разных классов, расположенных, более того, в разных модулях и, следовательно, невидимых ни друг для друга, ни для основной подпрограммы?

Comment: Может не стоит называть свой тип TList. Такой тип есть в Pascal.

Comment: @gregor вы абсолютно правы, так ошибка пропадает. Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит называть свой тип как TList. Такой тип есть в Pascal

Comment: Странно, т.к. совпадение имен типов/классов не должно вызывать таких проблем. Максимум что будет - ошибка компиляции при присвоении значений разных типов друг другу.